# How to deliver static HTML file with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have created a static HTML Report with css styles and will be putting this report on the server. The HTML file then get copied to S3 and a service will deliver the file to users inbox upon arrival in S3 bucket.

When the file is delivered to the users, it is missing the CSS. I am new to HTML/CSS and still learning. Can anyone suggest a solution to this?

Comment: [HTML/CSS Email](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/) is a different animal than HTML/CSS on a website. In short whatever you're trying is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<Style>{your CSS goes here}</Style>` tag in the head. you can learn more about it at this [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_newsletter.asp) page.